# CSS targeting if a DIV doesn't have a specific sibling

Tags: html, css

I'm working with markup generated by a third-party app so I'm branding it and running into a scenario I can't solve. Most of the time the HTML will have two `<div>`s in a container `<div>` that have the same class name of `formCol`. There's always a `clear` sibling, too:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <div class="formCol">Two Divs</div>
    <div class="formCol">With the Same Class</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Occasionally there's only one `.formCol` in the container. I'd like to be able target when the `formRow` has just one `formCol`, but because `clear` is still a sibling I can't use `:only-of-type` or `:only-child`.

```
<div class="formRow">
    <div class="formCol">One Div</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How can I target when `formRow` has only one `formCol` in it?

Comment: Is the structure _always_ going to be **either** two `formCol` divs followed by one `clear` div **or** one `formCol` followed by one `clear` div? In other words, those are the only two possible options?

Comment: If so, there are any number of pseudo-class solutions. `.formCol:first-child + .clear` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `.clear` is always there you can combine two `nth-` pseudo classes:

```css
/* it is the first child and the second last child at the same time */
:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">Two Divs</div>
  <div class="formCol">With the Same Class</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">One Div</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And if you only target [latest version of browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of) you can use new syntax of `:nth-child`:

```css
/* it is the first .formCol and the last .formCol at the same time */
:nth-child(1 of .formCol):nth-last-child(1 of .formCol) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">Two Divs</div>
  <div class="formCol">With the Same Class</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">One Div</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

or [`:has`](https://caniuse.com/css-has):

```css
/* it is the first .formCol and next sibling is .clear */
.formCol:first-child:has(+ .clear) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">Two Divs</div>
  <div class="formCol">With the Same Class</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">One Div</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer would benefit by what you mean by "modern" browsers and why (what part of the solution requires "modern" browsers?

Answer (score 1):

We can target the `.formRow` using `:has()` if it doesn't have 3 or more elements inside it, like so:

```css
.formRow:not(:has(:nth-child(3))) {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">Two Divs</div>
  <div class="formCol">With the Same Class</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="formRow">
  <div class="formCol">One Div</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Note, check your browser support for `:has()`.

Comment: It's all blue for me..

Comment: What browser are you using? @Wimanicesir

Comment: Firefox and yes still the same. Does indeed work on chrome for me

Comment: `:has` requires a modern browser https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: Firefox does still not support `:has()` yet, unless the user explicitly enables it via flags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility says it comes with v121, to be released 2023-12-19 though.

Comment: @SalmanA Come now, Firefox is a "modern browser" :-). That feature just doesn't have support _by default_ yet in Firefox. It has supported `:has()` behind a flag for like over a year.

Comment: @tyler can't edit comment. Anyway, :has is part of selector level 4 which is not finalized. I would avoid it, behavior could change, features might not make it to final version, you know.